# MS Access chart - how to change series line color in VBA

Tags: ms-access, graph, vba

I've wrote a code in MS Access VBA,

Dim grph As Object

Set grph = Forms![frm_MyForm]!gphMyGraph.Object

With grph.SeriesCollection(1)
 .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
end with

This result in runtime error 1004 "Applying color property to the interior class is not possible" (this is translation of the message from different language, it might bi slightly different in English version of MS Access). 
I've tried different combination of this code, but with the same result, looks like for some reasons I cannot change this value. Any ida why, and hot to make this code working?

Answer (score 0):

Error might be due no series in the collection

After `Set grph = Forms![frm_MyForm]!gphMyGraph.Object`, add the following

```
If grph.SeriesCollection.Count > 0 Then

grph.SeriesCollection(1) .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) 

End If
```